# textSize Property under Textview is not showing in my layout Editor?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I am begineer in Android Development. I am making a XML layout but the property of textSize not showing also the code which generated automatically when we type not generating like if we type match then studio will show match_parent that is not generating. How to solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"// this line is showing in black
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

also when I tried to drag and drop it again not showing attributes of textview like textstyle, textsize etc.

[image]

I am trying to increase my text size but the property in attributes not showing it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having project and/or IDE errors. Have you tried syncing with gradle or Invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio?

Comment: I created the new project and copy paste the code , it works but i am unable to solve the real problem. Yes, I upgraded the versions inside the gradle , restarted the studio but it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't mean upgrading the versions, but just syncing it. (Clicking the elephant on the top right corner).

Also try using the File -> Invalidate Caches functionality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be occured error, and TextView if in ConstraintLayout must be have app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf property

so I suggest below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your gradle config file(module level) and
set the attributes
compileSdk and targetSdk
with at most Android API version 32

Example:

```
android {
compileSdk 32
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.droidcafe"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0." + versionCode
//minimized code...
}
```